# Button disable/enable based on user control value from other user control c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control which has one Button which should enable/disable if i change the state value from other user control.

Can someone help me know how i can achieve this? How to capture the bool for the changes on the enable/disable button?

Usercontrol1 UTILS

```
    public Utilitaires()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new TCP());
    }

    //My button btnUndo created from the Visual interface

    public void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      my code...
    }
```

Usercontrol2 TCP

```
    //My method which should by the bool canredo change the enabled state of my button btnredo Usercontrol1

    public void Redo_CanRedoChanged(object Sender, bool CanRedo)
    {

     UTILS foo = new UTILS();

        foo.btnRedo.Enabled = CanRedo;// This is my problem to reach the button btnRedo UserControl 1
    }
```

Sorry for my English...! Thanks

Comment: This seems to be exactly how you would do it (except for the ellipsis, of course). What's the problem you see when you try it?

Comment: if i do for example Usercontrol1 foo = new Usercontrol1(), foo.btnRedo.Enabled = CanRedo;nothing is happening.

Comment: @Laurent what do you expect to happen with the above example?

Comment: @Fredy, if i do the above example, the button does not change state. I can't transfer bool value state btnRedo.Enabled to Usercontrol1 where my button is declared. Maybe I should to get the state do a public bool {get set}?

Comment: @Laurent there's a lot more. You don't give sufficient data for your problem to reproduce. Do you subscribe to an event with 'Redo_CanRedoChanged'? Shouldn't the bool be reversed: btnRedo.Enabled = !CanRedo?

Comment: @Fredy, the bool CanRedo is OK. The problem is to change the state Enable/disable of the Button BtnRedo in Usercontrol1. I update the edit. If i do this method nothing happens on the state of my button.

Comment: @Laurent thanks! in your new updated code, it is clear: you state a 'new' command but this will create another instance of the usercontrol, it's not that you want, you must use the already existing instance of this usercontrol.

Comment: Thanks @Freddy for your help. But I created my button in Usercontrol1 and I would like to change its enable/disable state in Usercontrol2. If i do public Usercontrol1 foo and execute i have "System.NullReferenceException". What is the "already instance of the usercontrol1" ?

Comment: @Laurent how do you create the instances of your usercontrols? Programmatically or with the Visual interface?  "already instance of the usercontrol1" --> if you have created one instance of your button, you must use this name to activate or deactivate a property. If you use 'new', you will create another object, it is not what you want.

Comment: @fredy, sorry to my late answer. The button btnRedo was create with visual interface in Usercontrol1. If i use the name btnredo in Usercontrol2 without nothing i can't reach it. That's why I created a new instance. i don't understand how to implement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok I get it; this is an excellent question you asked because you need 'accessibility' or 'persmission' if you wish from one usercontrol to another. This must be coded in the constructors of your usercontrols. (So this is why Ken's answer below can't work.) I'm back in a few moment with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Laurent, this is solved: as it may be complex, I detail all the steps for future readers.

First, I have created a UserControl named UserControl1; it contains only a button named button1. I will use this UserControl for both of yours to stay simple.

To have the UserControl1 ready in the toolbox on the left, I compile the program (F5) and stop it. Now, I drag two UserControls from the toolbox to the empty Form1. So, the instances created automatically are userControl11 and userControl12. I will make the first control the second one.

Add this code at the beginning of the UserControl.cs (before the contructor):

```
    public bool ButtonEnable
    {
        get => button1.Enabled;
        set { button1.Enabled = value; }
    }

    public UserControl1 InControl { get; set; }
```

The bool will make the state of the button accessible to any other object. I stated 'public' but 'internal' is enough if you work inside the same solution. Don't use 'private' else it won't be accessible.

The InControl property will set which other instance should be controlled by the current UserControl.

Now, I double click on the button in the UserControl1 to generate the delegate, complete it as follows:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InControl != null)
        {
            InControl.ButtonEnable = !InControl.ButtonEnable;
        }
    }
```

This will toggle the state of the controlled button.

Now, let's go back to the Form1.cs and modify the contructor by adding the second line:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl11.InControl = userControl12;
    }
```

It's done, the button of the first UserControl will toggle the state of the second UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is to enable/disable the control then,
Try:

```
// this is usually done by creating a control in
// the Winforms designer, not in directly in your code:
Usercontrol1 myUserControl = new Usercontrol1();

// class variable

bool controlEnabled = true;




public void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // As an example, this will toggle the control from
    // enabled to disabled.
    controlEnabled = !controlEnabled;
    myUserControl.Enabled = controlEnabled;             
}

// Additional info: if you want to disable only a button in your 
// user control then create a public method to disable the button
// ex:
public class MyUserControl 
{
  // other stuff
  public void EnableMyButton(bool enable)
  { 
      MyButton.Enable = enable;
  }
}

public void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // As an example, this will toggle the control from
    // enabled to disabled.
    controlEnabled = !controlEnabled;
    myUserControl.EnableMyButton(controlEnabled);             
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken for your answer but i would like to enabled/disabled the button btnredo directly from usercontrol2 with my method.

Comment: See Additional comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ken and @fredy for showing me a way. I found another solution that works in my case :

Usercontrol1 Utils

```
public static Utils Current = null;

public Utilitaires()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Tcp());

    Current = this;
}

//My button btnUndo created from the Visual interface

public void btnUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  my code...
}
```

Usercontrol2 Tcp

```
public Utils UndoRedo = Utils.Current;

public void Redo_CanRedoChanged(object Sender, bool CanRedo)
{

 UndoRedo.btnRedo.Enabled = CanRedo;

}
```

Thanks again for your help !

Comment: It's great Laurent if you found your own best coding! Cheers!